# Application hangs because of code in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Following is my code in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _sharedHandler = [TGProjectHandler sharedHandler];


    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 30)];
    _email.leftView = paddingView;
    _email.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    _password.leftView = paddingView;
    _password.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}
```

When application runs and this code is executed, application gets stuck. But if I comment out any one the following lines, application runs correctly.

```
    _email.leftView = paddingView;
    _email.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    _password.leftView = paddingView;
    _password.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Can someone point out the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to create padding view for each and every text field you want. i.e if you have two textfield to add padding view then creates two padding view and allocate separate to each text filed in viewDidLoad(). In your case you have made only one padding view.

```
UIView *paddingView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
self.eventTitleTxt.leftView = paddingView2;
self.eventTitleTxt.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```